# Logstash Optional Fields

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have log examples like this where uptime isn't always a field:

```
Oct 17 08:41:33 host-name 2y40w: %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGP: list 105 permitted tcp 1.2.3.4(17774) -> 0.0.0.0(22), 1 packet
Oct 17 13:32:26 host-name %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGP: list 105 permitted tcp 1.2.3.4(56200) -> 0.0.0.0(22), 1 packet
```

If i do regex like this:

```
   %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:log_server_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:cisco_host (%{DATA:uptime}:)? %{NOTSPACE:msgid}: \list %{NUMBER:acl} %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} %{NOTSPACE:source}+\(%{DATA:src_port}\) \-> %{NOTSPACE:dest}+\(%{DATA:dest_port}\), %{NUMBER:packets}
```

With a space between:

```
(%{DATA:uptime}:)? %{NOTSPACE:msgid}:
```

It will parse the log that includes uptime successfully, but not the log without uptime.

Without a space like:

```
(%{DATA:uptime}:)?%{NOTSPACE:msgid}:
```

It will parse the message that does not include the uptime.

I am a bit rusty with my regex so was hoping someone could help me figure out why this isn't taking as I really don't like the idea of adding another level of nested if statements when a conditional field like this should be available in regex.

edit:

also tried:

```
(?<uptime>[ywd0-9]+):
```

Which does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enclose the whole part of the uptime pattern + whitespace with an optional group:

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:log_server_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:cisco_host}( %{DATA:uptime}:)? %{NOTSPACE:msgid}: \list %{NUMBER:acl} %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} %{NOTSPACE:source}+\(%{DATA:src_port}\) \-> %{NOTSPACE:dest}+\(%{DATA:dest_port}\), %{NUMBER:packets}
                                                              ^^               ^^
```

Comment: if I do it that way and take the closing curly brace off of cisco_host it doesn't work at all, but if I did it that way and include the closing curly brace for cisco host it will parse the uptime, but won't parse without the uptime

Comment: %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:log_server_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:cisco_host}( %{DATA:uptime}:)? %{NOTSPACE:msgid}: \list %{NUMBER:acl} %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} %{NOTSPACE:source}+\(%{DATA:src_port}\) \-> %{NOTSPACE:dest}+\(%{DATA:dest_port}\), %{NUMBER:packets}
^I lied, this seems to be working. Thank you

Comment: @wahyzcrak Yeah, I've just noticed you removed the closing `}` from `cisco_host`, I have put it back.